# Не работает SD карта в fedora linux

Tags: linux, fedora, sd

В ноутбуке есть SD ридер, но когда я вставляю карту она не определяется.
Ридер в lspci видится довольно странно:

```
Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller
```

При попытке монтирования выдаёт

```
can't read superblock
```

fdisk карту не видит, dmesg после подключения и до перезагрузки спамит

```
[ 3976.256052] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: DPC: containment event, status:0x1f01 source:0x0000
[ 3976.256053] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: DPC: unmasked uncorrectable error detected
[ 3976.256058] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 3976.256059] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   device [8086:06b6] error     status/mask=00200000/00010000
[ 3976.256060] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
[ 3976.256068] alcor_pci 0000:08:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
[ 3977.486772] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: Data Link Layer Link Active not set in 1000 msec
[ 3977.486776] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: subordinate device reset failed
[ 3977.486793] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: device recovery failed
```

lsblk при этом SDшку видит.

Пробовал форматировать:

```
Warning: could not erase sector 2: Input/output error
Creating filesystem with 1943552 4k blocks and 486720 inodes

Filesystem UUID: 2c15cbc5-6df9-4e58-a17d-391a441f479f

Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632

Allocating group tables: done                            
Warning: could not read block 0: Input/output error
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Input/output error
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system
```

Ничего особо не поменялось. Далее пытался восстанавливать суперблок:

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768(и другие) /dev/mmcblk0
```

Получилось не очень:

```
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Fedora 38. Ноутбук HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 17-cd1xxx.

Comment: sd карту пробовали через usb-переходник  подключать ? попробуйте также перед форматированием почистить лишние __магические блоки__ на sd карте с помощью команды `wipefs -a /dev/...`

Comment: usb переходника у меня нет, а после выполнения команды ничего не поменялось

Comment: судя по интернетам данный картридер довольно проблемный. Закиньте еще для полноты картины вывод `lspci -vnn |awk '/card reader/,/^$/'` относящегося к вашему кардридеру и укажите версию ядра `uname -a`